# How to make your EditText italicized?

Tags: android

```
  android:textStyle="italic"
```

This does not italicize the editText.

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTxt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:singleLine="true" 
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" 

            >
        </EditText>
```

Could you help? Thank you so much in advance.

I now found that there is something wrong with Galaxy Note 2, when you try to italicize texts in editText. 4/18/2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set text as italic, you can do the following:

`EditText.setText(Html.fromHtml("<small><i>" + "Text Hint Here" + "</i></small>"));`

If you would like the italic text to be a hint - when the EditText is empty for example - you must implement a method to check the text length, and when it is equal to zero, apply the above code.

Try this **updated** option:-

Create a new style:-

```
    <style name="editStyle">
            <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    </style>
```

and use it this way - it works :)

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTxt"
        style="@style/editStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="EditText"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="14dp" >
</EditText>
```

**SnapShot**:- 
[image: Working snap]

Comment: this made an string with italicized style, but once you erase the strings, you don't get italic again. Plain text afterwards.

Comment: The updated version did not work. I checked that style was correctly linked by changing the id of the style, but the editText strings were not italicized.

Comment: really amazed as to how it didn't work. I tried it on 2-3 emulators and it worked fine on all of them.

Comment: I will try on the emulator and see it work. I was testing in Galaxy Note 2.

Comment: OK, this is very interesting. Your answer works for the emulator. I will mark the answer as correct and ask in a Samsung forum to fix that. Thank you very much. Your codes still doesn't work in real Galaxy Note 2 device though. But thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
youredittext.setTypeface(null,Typeface.ITALIC);
```

Comment: I tried this already, this didn't work :( I think this only works for iTextView.

Comment: It will work  in the device....And also try  download Italic typeface and do to like this Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Your font file"); 
editText.setTypeface(italic);

Comment: I tried that. I didn't change the font. It is the default font. it is very odd that android:textStyle="bold" works but android:textStyle="italic" doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

EditText inherits from TextView

```
editText.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
editText.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
editText.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
```

Use what you want.

**UPDATE**

Do you use custom font? Try

```
mTextView.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.ITALIC), Typeface.ITALIC)
```

**Edit**
I think its an android platform issue.

Look at [Issue 22867: Incorrect layout preview when ITALIC text style used](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22867)

It doesn't show up on the layout's graphical representation but works correctly when you build and run the app.

**Update:**
If you want to preview for designing xml layout then just use

```
android:typeface="serif"
```

In this `android:textStyle="italic"` works. And text will displayed in italic style in graphical layout editor.

Its only works for this **serif typeface**.

Comment: It is so weird. android:textStyle="bold" and editText.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD); work but these don't work: editText.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC); and android:textStyle="italic"

Comment: I don't use custom font. I use whatever font, the default had it. I didn't change the font. I will +1 all the answers once I get the answers because you guys are trying hard. The line of code didn't work for me either.

Comment: Even with serif, italic doesn't work. bold doesn't work either in this case. (android:textStyle="bold" &android:textStyle="italic" both don't work for the serif font.)

Answer (score 1):

inside string

```
<string name="username"><i>Username</i></string>
```

xml file..

```
<EditText android:hint="@string/username" />
```